# How many re-rolls does Alter Fortune grant?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

The spell "alter fortune" allows the subject of the spell to immediately re-roll any dice-roll the character just made. It also states that the target 'must abide by the second roll'.

With that in mind- How many re-rolls can the spell grant a character for a single roll? RAW it seems to state that it allows you to roll a specific check as often as you can cast the spell, but still restricts you to abide only by the second roll made, no matter how many rolls you actually make. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Once Per Caster

The key to this question is the casting time of the spell.

> Casting Time: 1 immediate action

And an Immediate Action...

> Swift Action A swift action consumes a very small amount of time, but
>   represents a larger expenditure of effort and energy than a free
>   action. You can perform only a single swift action per turn.
>
> Immediate Action An immediate action is very similar to a swift
>   action, but can be performed at any time — even if it's not your turn.

So you only get 1 Immediate Action per round. Which means the roll would resolve before a caster could cast it a second time.

But wait! What if I have more casters willing to use spell slots on this one roll? The short answer is that the "second" roll is the re-roll, every time. Each time the spell is cast it's only looking at two rolls. The roll that was made pre-cast, and the roll made post-cast. The spell doesn't know or care about any rolls made from other casters.